# How to show newly added (by Javascript) DOM Elements after refresh?

Tags: php

I have a JavaScript function which multiplies a DOM element.

I hit it 2 times (for example) and I get 3 Elements like this:

```
<!-- How to show all my new Elements after refresh? -->
<tr id="toBeMultiplied">
    <td>
        <!-- How to echo the value of this input? -->
        <input type="text" name="numbers[]" /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <!-- How to echo the value of this input? -->
        <input type="text" name="titles[]" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <!-- How to echo the value of this input? -->
        <input type="text" name="lengths[]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

But this is just a small part of a big Form! When I click on Submit, those new Elements I've just created disappear.

So, I want to **make my new Elements to not disappear**.

Comment: you can use jquery to search trough your table and get the values.

Comment: Disappear how? When you get the result of the post, they're not there? No surprise on that one - the resulting page is generated by you on the server, and will not have any fields in it taht you have no put in there yourself.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with PHP?

Comment: Do you mean the values are not in `$_POST` or that when you go back to the page the form resets back to the original number of input fields?

Comment: Yeees, this is what I mean :)

Comment: I need somehow to POST values of these 3 input fields foreach new TR Element.

Comment: So when you submit the form and do `print_r( $_POST )` you don't see data typed into the new input fields?

Comment: No, I see the values by print_r($_POST)! But how to echo them continuously on my form, after a refresh for example? Values remain but inputs disappear!

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't want to refresh the page, rather you need to use ajax to submit the data, so you don't loose your dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count how many values are in, say, numbers array on POST.

For example:
`$i = count($_POST['numbers'])`

And then create a loop that will print the form as many times as it existed before.

If you end up using `$i` as a count of elements, you could then fill in the previous values back into the form as such: `$_POST['numbers'][$i]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to intercept the POST statement and grab the newly created elements and send the data via AJAX json.

The second option would be to include an AJAX request inside the function that adds the row and puts something in the session that says "HEY I HAVE +1 Mushroom rows!"